# Backbone.js - how to include an external HTML fragment

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, pjax

I have pre-rendered HTML fragments in my filesystem. Is it possible to load HTML fragments in **backbone.js**? I'm looking for something similar to **ng-include** of **Angular.js**

for example, in my file system (frag.html)

```
<h1>I'm a fragment</h1>
```

Should be injected to the template in a given placeholder location

```
<div id="ph">
   <!-- INJECTED -->
   <h1>I'm a fragment</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, we have this placeholder:

```
<div id="ph"></div>
```

and this HTML in frag.html file:

```
<div>
    <h1>I am</h1>
    <span>an HTML fragment</span>
</div>
```

Let us define our custom `PrerenderedView` with a special `render` method with the jQuery function [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) inside:

```
window.PrerenderedView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.$el.load(this.options.ajax_template_path, _.bind(this.onRender, this));
    return this;
  },
  onRender: function() {
    // do some stuff here, for example
    var h1 = this.$('h1');
    var text = this.model.get('some_value');
    setTimeout(function() {
      h1.text(text);
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

At the moment of instantiation of the `PrerenderedView` we should pass an option `ajax_template_path` (which is 'frag.html' in our case).

```
$(function() {
  new window.PrerenderedView({
    el: $('#ph'),
    model: new Backbone.Model({some_value: 'It was'}),
    ajax_template_path: 'frag.html'
  }).render();
});
```

And, of course, we do not forget about [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) if we are going to work without a server. For example, we can start chrome with the flag '--allow-file-access-from-files'.