# Django template tags to Backbone.js template tags: include a separate HTML file

Tags: html, django, templates, backbone.js

I want to convert the "include" template tags in this HTML code I have from Django server-based to Backbone.js so that I can separate my frontend from the backend and not mix them together in my HTML code; I am using three of them to add code from three separate HTML files. I'm still new to Backbone.js as well.

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gregory Desrosiers (uWaterloo) - To Do List</title>

        <!-- Links to static pages in Django development server are not shown for brevity. -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- User Account Bar (includes modals) -->
        {% include "UserAccountBar.html" %}
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

        <!-- Main Body -->
        <div id="mainBodyBlock">
           {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <!-- The original To Do Task form is not shown for brevity. -->
            <br/><br/>

            {% regroup task_list by category_of_task as tasks_organized_by_category_list %}
            <!-- List of checkboxes based on the categories -->
            <div id="categoryCheckboxes">
                {% include "TaskChecklistCategoryCheckboxes.html" %}
            </div>

            <br/><br/><br/>

            <!-- List of tasks from backend -->
            <div id="listOfThingsToDo">
                {% include "ListOfTasks.html" %}
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
            {% else %}
                <!-- Original code is not shown for brevity. -->
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know there's the jQuery script approach according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file), but suppose that I am not allowed to use anything else than Backbone.js for my frontend. There's also [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053494/backbone-js-how-to-include-an-external-html-fragment), which my initial impression is that it's kind of cumbersome to use.

Does Backbone.js have a template tag I can use to include separate HTML files?

Comment: Something I forgot to mention; this blog tells me about an include tag, but that involves writing a lot of code. http://emptysqua.re/blog/adding-an-include-tag-to-underscore-js-templates/
I'm wondering if there's a shorter way of doing this.

Comment: Okay, readers, read up: I'm doing my frontend development approach now in a different way, but I'm leaving this question up for other readers to see this as an example.